# How to create a new rest url prefix in Wordpress REST API?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'd like to have in my website **two url prefixes** to reach two different api base paths, in particular:

I need to keep `wp-json` url prefix
I need to create a new prefix called `api`, so I can create new routes and endpoints there.
I've found this method

```
add_filter( 'rest_url_prefix', 'rest_url_prefix' );

function rest_url_prefix( ) {
  return 'api';
}
```

but it hides also `wp-json`, while I'd need to create a new url prefix, different from it but working concurrently.
How can I achieve it? 
Thanks

Comment: the filter you added  will crush the wp-json

Comment: In fact! I don't want to crush it, I want to create another base for the api

Answer (score 0):

From your description I believe you want to develop two different APIs. You can do without altering the prefix. Actually, this filter alter wp-json by your custom prefix which is base URL of API endpoints.

Instead of changing prefix, you could create two different end points for two different APIs.

1. If you have one API that creates post, you could use

`add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route( 'yourprefix1/v1', '/create/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET', // You can use 'POST' as well
            'callback' => 'create_post',
        ));
    });`

The URL for this would be http://example.com/wp-json/yourprefix1/v1/create/

2. Another API that create users could have endpoints like

   `add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
       register_rest_route( 'yourprefix2/v1', '/create/user/', array(
           'methods' => 'GET', // You can use 'POST' as well
           'callback' => 'create_user',
       ));
   });`

The URL for this would be http://example.com/wp-json/yourprefix2/v1/create/user/

Hope this may help you!

Comment: i think he is looking to keep the wp-json as prefix and create another one named api so you can reach the api url by : /wp-json and also /api at the same time .

Comment: He may! but he has to use the API WP way to avoid any issues. To simply differentiate API he can add one desire name into URL instead of making change in base URL.

Comment: I know it's due to avoid issues and I understand it, but I'd need to call two different APIs, one the normal mydomain.com/wp-json but also another one on mydomain.com/api

Comment: nothing to avoid in this case. It's just simply something that you want to change mandatory things. You may think it different way. Can you elaborate why do you want two different base path for one single domain? Community may have different approach to solve your issue.

Comment: Actually I'd need to leave wp-json unchanged and public, but I don't want to expose some routes, so my idea was to leave wp-json and to create a new base. In this way wp-json remains public but it won't show my private routes in "/"

Comment: I'm afraid that this could be done. Hope you've gone through (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228585/hiding-wordpress-rest-api-v2-endpoints-from-public-viewing) this answer

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you were looking for (2+ years ago):

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    "api/(.+)/?$",
    'index.php?rest_route=/$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

This does, however, create the ability to access the api from two prefixes by rewriting `/api` to `/wp-json`. You could customize things from there, but it probably isn't as straight-forward as what you were asking.

So you could use both:

1. `http://www.example.com/wp-json/v2`
2. `http://www.example.com/api/v2`

If you wanted to use `wp-json/api/v2` instead:

1. `http://www.example.com/wp-json/api/v2`
2. `http://www.example.com/api/v2`

You would want to make sure you register your routes without api (eg: `register_rest_route( 'v2', ...`), and then change the api prefix:

```
add_filter( 'rest_url_prefix', function( $prefix ) {
    return "$prefix/api";// wp-json/api
});
```

***Flush your rewrite rules after this change***.

But that will still change up your default endpoints... Maybe this can help somebody else. It is a starting point.

And make sure you add the rewrite rule within an action call late enough in the process. `init` works:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "api/(.+)/?$",
        'index.php?rest_route=/$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
});
```